Scheduled reminder complex timing
I'd like to send out a series of scheduled reminders to new contacts, as a kind of 'welcome' series.
I want the first one to go out on Friday at 11 am, for all new contacts that haven't yet received it and who were created more than 36 hours previously (because we want time on Thursday to dedupe these new contacts to make sure they're really new).
So the timing is something like "On Friday, for all new contacts more than 36 hrs old".
Is that possible with the scheduling rules?
One option I considered is just using the "after 36 hrs" timing configuration, but to restrict the system job for that reminder to only get triggered on Friday. So I'd need to tell the usual send_reminder system job to exclude that particular scheduled reminder (but still run the other ones), and then have a dedicated cron that ran the send_reminder only for that reminder.
Does that sound like a reasonable approach? Are there more obvious ones?
It's kind of like the rule for Easter!

My reading of this line: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/6f411e1b07dd1d367f78d81c5dcbc8d8deb62b54/api/v3/Job.php#L220
is that the send_reminder job can take an argument of an id, presumably the id of the scheduled reminders (from the civicrm_action_schedule table).
So I can modify the existing scheduled reminder to give it an id argument, and then a new one won't run until I set up a scheduled reminder job for it, which can be run via a linux cron, for example.
